# Are all bot killer weapons strange?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I got my first botkiller today as a gift from a kind player whom I kept saving from pyros on an enemy team. Incidentally enough we were both playing as a red spy. So when the next round started he sent me a trade request and gave me a strange killstreak botkiller knife (silver). He said it was a sort of "thank you" for keeping him alive and taking an arrow in the head (literally). He had two of them. Afterwards I thanked him and continued playing. After the match was over I went on scrap.tf to see if I could find any other botkillers. I would like to collect one for each class but all I have see are the expensive stranges and Australiam ones. Is there any cheap regular ones?

Answer (score 4):

**Actually, all Botkiller and Australium weapons are Strange by default.** They do not come in any other quality.

They will tend to be expensive due to their rarity: Botkiller weapons are awarded to you upon the completion of any Mann Vs Machine tour except for Two Cities. Each tour grants either of two different Botkiller variants, one of which is rarer than the other. Depending on what weapon you get, it may be more valuable than the others.

Comment: The rare ones are Blood (Operation: Oil Spill), Gold Mark 1 (Operation: Steel Trap), Gold Mark 2 (Operation: Mecha Engine), and Diamond (Operation: Gear Grinder).